# Upgrading to webpack 4, import not working

Tags: javascript, webpack, import, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm in the process of upgrading to webpack `4.6.0` from `3.0.0`.
Everything builds fine, but when it comes to executing the code in the browser, imports are not working properly.

This is mu setup:

package.json

```
"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
"babel-core": "^6.26.0",
"babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
"babel-jest": "^22.2.2",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
"babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
"babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^1.0.1",
"babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "6.18.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-object-assign": "^6.22.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
"webpack": "^4.6.0",
"webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.11.1",
"webpack-cli": "^2.0.15",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.3",
"workbox-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0"
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
      "env",
      "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
      "add-module-exports",
      "transform-class-properties",
      "transform-object-rest-spread",
      "transform-object-assign",
      "syntax-dynamic-import"
  ],
  "env": {
      "test": {
          "plugins": [
              "dynamic-import-node"
          ]
      }
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    include: [
      path.resolve('src')
    ],
    use: [
      { loader: 'babel-loader' },
      ...
    ]
}
```

And then when it comes to being executed, this happens:

[image: dev-tools]

`progressiveImage` is a react component which when being debugged, it has no default from import.

Can you spot anything wrong from this?

Thanks in advance.